# my application insert duplicate data on database

Tags: android

my applicaiton work fine when no internet vailable fetch data form databsae but problem is every time its inseert same data on database so data will show multiples time help me how to restrict database to safe only unique data in database

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
static ArrayList<String> Category_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
String _response;
String status;
GridView gridview;
private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private boolean isUpdate;
int IOConnect = 0;
 // flag for Internet connection status
  Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

 // Connection detector class
 ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mHelper=new DbHelper(this);
       cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(MainActivity.this);
      isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

      // check for Internet status
      if (isInternetPresent) {
          // Internet Connection is Present
          // make HTTP requests
          new TheTask().execute();

      } else {
          // Internet connection is not present
          // Ask user to connect to Internet
          displayData();
      }
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Subcategory.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("Category_ID", Category_ID.get(position));
            iMenuList.putExtra("Category_name", Category_name.get(position));
            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    });

}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
}

public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

SelectMenuAPI = "http://www.aaaa/_webservices/mobile_api.php?response=getmaincategories";

        clearData();
        URL = SelectMenuAPI;
        URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

        try {

            Log.i("url", "" + URL2);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL2);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {

            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(result);

            status = json2.getString("Status");
            if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = object.getString("category_id");
                    String name =object.getString("name");
                    String  image_path = object.getString("image_path");

                    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MYID,id);

                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,name);
                    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,image_path );

                    System.out.println("");
                    if(isUpdate)
                    {    
                        //update database with new data 
                dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //insert data into database
                        dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                    }
                    //close database
                    dataBase.close();
                }
            }

            else {
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayData();
        }
}

private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

    Category_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));

   Category_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));

   Category_image.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    gridview.setAdapter(cla);

    mCursor.close();
}
```

**Database Class**

```
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";

public static final String KEY_MYID="myid";


public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY  
     KEY,"+KEY_MYID+" TEXT, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" BLOB)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

    }
```

Comment: add unique constraint to your column in database to prevent duplicates

Comment: how???  tell me where????

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_constraints.htm

Comment: tell me 1 more thing this is my query which return all data form data base
Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
     + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

how do i change this to get only that data which id is 17

Comment: @user2914381 Try out like `Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DbHelper.TABLE_NAME WHERE id = "+17+"", null);`

Comment: what about only unique entry in database how do that? my database enter every time same data so  multiple data found

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: ur isUpdate flag is always false ?? When shall it be set to true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the isUpdate value before the if condition.

like

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.getIsRecordPresent(id);
if(c.getcount > 0) {
    isUpdate= true;
}

// the if condition here.
```

where getIsRecordPresent will return the cursor if the row with the id is present in the db the cursor.getcount method will return > 0 else value 0

If a row exists, then set the isUpdate to true else to false

Answer (score 0):

A GUID value is intended to be unique across tables and even databases so,  make a `UNIQUE` index for the GUID. I think this is what you need.you Have to make add `unique constrain` to any one of the column other then KEY_ID .

Do it like this

```
String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARYKEY,"+KEY_MYID+" TEXT, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" BLOB,UNIQUE("+KEY_FNAME+"))";
```